# .NET 6 TempData is always empty in controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-6.0, tempdata

I know this seems like a duplicate of so many other issues, but I've tried all the suggestion and is still not working.

I have 2 dummy buttons on view, one to set some value into `TempData` and another one to get the value of previously saved `TempData`, and on the action to get `TempData`, is always empty.

I've configure my `TempData` provider as described in [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-6.0#configure-the-tempdata-provider) but is still not working, I'm not sure what did I missed in Program.cs or is my configuration sequence is wrong?

Program.cs

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();

//Tried .AddController().AddSessionStateTempDataProvider() & AddControllersWithViews().AddSessionStateTempDataProvider(), all not working
builder.Services.AddMvc().AddSessionStateTempDataProvider();

builder.Services.AddSession(options =>
{
    options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
});

builder.Services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(opts => opts.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null);

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseSession();
app.MapRazorPages();

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Map}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});

app.Run();
```

My cshtml code:

```js
$('#btnTestSetTempData').on('click', function () {
    var response = {}; //some JSON data here
    
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("TestSetTempData", "MyTest")',
        cache: false,
        traditional: true,
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(response),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
            console.log(`${Date.now()} - ${data}`);
        },
        error: function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            
            console.log('Set TempData Error : ' + errorThrown);
        }
    });
});

$('#btnTestGetTempData').on('click', function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("TestGetTempData", "MyTest")',
        cache: false,
        traditional: true,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
            console.log(`${Date.now()} - ${data}`);
        },
        error: function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log('Get TempData Error : ' + errorThrown);
        }
    });
});
```

MyTest controller:

```cs
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult TestSetTempData([FromBody] SomeModel theModel)
{
    TempData["SomeModel"] = JsonSerializer.Serialize(theModel);
    TempData.Keep("SomeModel");
    return Json(null);
}

public ActionResult TestGetTempData()
{
    //TempData count is always 0 and will jump to the last line
    if (TempData["SomeModel"] != null)
    {
        var viewModel = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<SomeModel>(TempData["SomeModel"] as string);
        TempData.Keep();
        return Json(viewModel.CallId);
    }
    return Json(null);
}
```

Comment: It shouldn't even reach `TestGetTempData` as you are calling it with a POST. It's also not clear why you are trying to abuse `TempData` as the session storage instead of just using the session storage.

Comment: Hi, could you elaborate more on how to use the session storage? I'm converting some old csproj from .NET Framework to .NET Core, and it was using TempData to store value so I continue to use it.
Yes it can reach `TestGetTempData`, I put a break point in the code and it did reach.

Comment: Does this help? https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/session-state-in-asp-net-core/#:~:text=Session%20is%20a%20feature%20in%20ASP.NET%20Core%20that,SessionId%20is%20stored%20on%20the%20client%20at%20cookie.

Comment: @QiangFu
Thank you, I tried this and getting strange behavior. I click button in random sequence Set -> Get -> Set -> Get etc etc; sometime it get null, sometime it can get value. Is this because of the session options `IdleTimeout` I set in Program.cs?

Comment: The session default timeout time is 20 minutes. You can custom by `builder.Services.AddSession(options =>
{
    options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60)});` in program.cs.

Comment: Ya I noticed I configure the IdleTimeout to 10secs which explains why the weird behavior of sometimes not getting the value, thank you for your explanation!